# Need to eliminate the "Add a Menu" text on my site

Tags: css

I need to get rid of the "Add a Menu" text on my site. Tried to figure it out but getting frustrated.

[image: screenshot of my web page in browser]

Tried just eliminating the text with the inspect tool in Chrome browser. Also tried `display:none` which is there now. Just need to get rid of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set display property to none

```
#site-navigation .menu > li > a {
  display:none;
}
```

```css
#site-navigation .menu > li > a {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.Thank you for replying so quickly.